# How to include static libraries which have same names for OBJECT files within them?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode4

I am developing an iPad app in which I have included 2 third party static libraries. The names of the object files in these 2 libraries are same. On building the app I am getting

> "Apple Mach -O (id) error"

because of the same names of the object files in those 2 libraries.
How to solve this problem?

Error looks like:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _T_strcpy in /Users/indiait-supportservices/Desktop/untitled folder/Universal/lib/simulator/libSecurIDLib.a(mem.o) and /Users/indiait-supportservices/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReceiverForiOS-aqpprpcivvjjadbsutqqmtjsoczk/Build/Intermediates/ReceiverForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp iPad.build/Objects-normal/i386/pdcrypte2.o for architecture i386

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 

failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Looks to me like it's a duplicate symbol, not a duplicate object file name.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes Daniel its a duplicate symbols. Can you plz tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Waiting for the solution.Plz anybody has some sugggestions??

Comment: Are you really sure that you did not include some library twice?

Answer (score 0):

Are you building for one architecture? If you are building for multiple architectures and use the `-all_load` linker flag, this breaks the linker's ability to ignore symbols that are defined for multiple architectures. As a test, try building just for armv6 and see if the error goes away.

There is a good blog post [here](http://blog.binaryfinery.com/universal-static-library-problem-in-iphone-sd) and a similar question discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2300867/257550).

Finally, you can add the following env var to debug problems with overriding categories:
`OBJC_PRINT_REPLACED_METHODS=YES`. This will log which method names have been overridden by categories, just in case that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two modules defining the same function, one in `libSecurIDLib.a(mem.o)` and `pdcrypte2.o`. These should be in their own namespaces (C++) or they should be prefixed so they don't collide (C).

There are [work arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940384/how-to-deal-with-symbol-collisions-between-statically-linked-libraries/6940389#6940389) if that's impossible, but it's better name things safely.