# Duplicate symbol error when linking two different library

Tags: ios, xcode

PLATFORM AND VERSION
iOS
Mac OS X 10.7.4
XCode 4.5

Hardware: Mac mini, Model No. A1347, processer: 2.3 GHz, Intel Core i5, memory: 8 GB, 1600 MHz DDR3

**DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM**
I am responsible to abstract some common codes into a static library for all iOS team in my company, and I have to resolve this problem.

If I want to link with static library A.a and B.a, and both A.a and B.a depends on C.a, the link progress will be failed with duplicate symbol error. Is there any resolution?

This problem can be more complex, all A.a, B.a and C.a have categories, A.a is using 1.0 version of C.a, but B.a is using 2.0 version of C.a.

I have abstracted the situation into a project, which can be accessed by:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/89544999/%E5%BD%92%E6%A1%A3.zip

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937501/static-libraries-have-same-function-names-causing-duplicate-symbol-error, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940384/how-to-deal-with-symbol-collisions-between-statically-linked-libraries/6940389#6940389 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300867/how-can-i-avoid-duplicate-symbol-errors-in-xcode-with-shared-static-libraries

Comment: Carl Norum's answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300867/how-can-i-avoid-duplicate-symbol-errors-in-xcode-with-shared-static-libraries looks best.