# Dealing with Class Ambiguity without changing the library code

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a C++ code that links two shared libraries (let's say, foo1.so and foo2.so). In both libraries I have a class called "Mesh", and the compiler cannot know which one I am trying to use when I try to instantiate the class Mesh (obviously I know which one I want to instantiate). I get the "error: reference to ‘Mesh’ is ambiguous"

Of course I could alter the source code of one of the libraries, wrapping the Mesh class around a namespace and that would solve the problem. I would like to avoid changing the library's code, though. Is there a way to remove this ambiguity in the source file which uses the libraries?

Thank you,
Rafael.

Comment: Sorry, but the answer is no. You can not differentiate other than by using namespace. This is why per-library namespace is considered a good thing.

Comment: Are these dynamic or static libs? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9183400/669576) mentions creating 2 dynamically linked libs - each one statically links to one of the conflicting libs.

Comment: If you are using dynamic libraries, you can load each dynamicaly (see [dl](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html) ) and then use the handle to differentiate the calls.

Answer (score 0):

By using dynamic libs (`.so` in linux), you can load each one and use each handle to differentiate call.
See [Dynamically Loaded (DL) Libraries](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html)

For example :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

class Meshib
{
    void * _handle;
    double (*_cosine)(double);

public:
    Meshib( const char * libraryPath)
    {
        char *error;

        _handle = dlopen (libraryPath, RTLD_LAZY);
        if (!_handle) {
            fputs (dlerror(), stderr);
            exit(1);
        }
        
        _cosine = reinterpret_cast<decltype(_cosine)>( dlsym(_handle, "cosine") );
        if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
            fputs(error, stderr);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    ~Meshib() {
        dlclose(_handle);
    }

    double cosine(double v) { return (*_cosine)(v); }
};



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Meshib meshLib1( "foo1.so" );
    Meshib meshLib2( "foo2.so" );

    printf("%f\n", meshLib1.cosine(2.0));
    printf("%f\n", meshLib2.cosine(2.0));
}
```

See [this article](https://theo-penavaire.medium.com/loading-of-a-c-class-from-a-shared-library-modern-c-722d6a830a2b) for C++ class dynamic load.