# Duplicate symbol error when linking multiple static libraries.

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, static-libraries, duplicate-symbol

There are a fair number of related questions out there already, but I'm just not getting this resolved. I'm building an application that includes two separate static libraries: RestKit and another that's on NDA. When I build, I'm getting a Apple Mach-O linker error as follows:

```
duplicate symbol _NewBase64Decode 
in /Users/geraldwburke/Desktop/iOS Programming/MyApp/someLib.a(NSData+Base64.o) 
and /Users/geraldwburke/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAppddlwzdeskfwaxyargomvfhurvxzi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRestKit.a(NSData+Base64.o) 
for architecture armv7
```

Now, I've seen some potential fixes out there. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940384/how-to-deal-with-symbol-collisions-between-statically-linked-libraries/6940389#6940389) seemed promising. I also tried to add a build rule using the script from [this blog entry](http://blog.binaryfinery.com/universal-static-library-problem-in-iphone-sd). I've tried adding and removing -ObjC, -all_load, and -force_load linker flags. No matter what I have tried, I still get that same error. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

BTW I will delete my identical post. Posted it on the wrong acct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to modify the source code of one of those libraries to *not* define `NewBase64Decode`.  RestKit is open source; I don't know if you have the source to your secret NDA library.

Comment: Modify source code to _not_ define NewBase64Decode or change NewBase64Decode to something else (MyNewBase64Decode perhaps!)