# How to call the same function from a linked framework?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Working with Xcode.
I got framework `A`.
I would like to create a framework `A_intercept`; which implements the same exported API functions from `A` and will eventually forward the same function calls to A. So I create `A_intercept`, and added `A` to the linked frameworks in "Link Binary with Libraries"

Now, I got some function M in `A`, `A_intercept`, will also implement it and name it M as well so it could be intercepted; however, How then A_interecept can forward the call to `A`; wouldn't that be a recursive call?

Comment: You're going to need to do symbol re-writing. You can use a ld script to prefix all the symbols in library A, and then implement the real symbols in library B.

But be aware that anything that uses strings (`dlsym`, `NSClassFromString`) will have problems.

There's unfortunately not really a way to do this at runtime. You *can* do it on the simulator only with mach_override (see https://github.com/richardjrossiii/mach_override_example), but if you're looking to use this in production you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157680/how-can-i-get-gcc-to-add-a-prefix-to-all-symbol-names

Comment: Thanks @RichardJ.RossIII ; I was wondering if there someway to accomplish that w/o messing with A, given that ObjC runtime keeps surprising me with ticks could be done with it. This is not a production code though.

Comment: You can do that easily with the Objective-C runtime environment. But *functions*  are not dispatched by the RTE, but called directly. *Messages*  are dispatched to *methods*.