# Shared library name collisions

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, visibility, name-clash

I'm distributing a shared library (C++) and a python module that uses this library. I build a modified version of Bullet Physics Library (as a CMake subproject).
I only use Bullet classes and functions in one file `bullet_interface.cpp` and all the Bullet stuff is hidden inside `namespace { ... }`.

The problem is that some other libraries require Bullet as a system dependency and link to the system version of Bullet. In fact, one of the dependencies of my library (`libopenrave`) exports Bullet symbols. (More specifically, it sometimes dynamically loads a plugin that exports Bullet symbols).

I'm wondering if there's a way to build my library so `bullet_interface.cpp` uses the correct Bullet functions, but then my library doesn't make any of the Bullet symbols visible.
I can't use the system bullet because I had to make changes to the source code.
One hacky solution would be to rename all of the Bullet functions and classes using a search and replace (almost all contain the string "bt"). Is there a better way?

Comment: The obvious solution is to get your fixes into the main `Bullet` library and use THAT as the system library.

Comment: Can you just ensure your modified version is loaded first and satisfies all the dependencies in the other libraries, so they don't need the system one?

Comment: So libopenrave exports bullet symbols and links with bullet library, while your plugin uses exactly the same bullet symbols and is being shipped with the modified bullet library? If so, you may try to build your modified bullet library as a static lib, link it into your plugin, and ensure that all bullet symbols in your plugin are hidden. Your plugin code will use them, while they will not be exported in dynamic symbol table. If bullet makefiles or code attributes are explicitly setting visibility, you'll have to hack it, maybe using binutils to change symbol visibility before linking objects?

Comment: I have a partial solution, building on Al's suggestion. (1) I set -fvisibility=hidden and use a DLL_EXPORT macro to control visibility. (2) instead of linking to a bullet shared library, I made a unity build of bullet (i.e., a cpp file that includes all of the bullet cpp files) and I build that along with my shared lib. Now my library isn't exporting any bullet symbols. Unfortunately, I still get a name collision when the system Bullet shared library gets loaded.

Comment: What platform is this? Runtime linker behaviour isn't particularly portable ...

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit of a roundabout way to accomplish what you want, but it beats a search-and-replace in bullet code.

You can try 'prefixing' symbols in the bullet library using the `objcopy` utility like this:

```
objcopy --prefix-symbols=old_ bullet.a
```

This *should* work with a dynamic library as well, but you'll have to try it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6940389/1257977) for details.