# Could two dynamic libraries with class with the same name be linked in the same program?

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

If I have two dynamic libraries which provided by two different suppliers, and they have one class with the same name, and they have no namespace.
And I want to use these two classes together in one program at the same time.So could it work?

If it could, how would I write my CMakeList to do the link?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox title and body say "dynamic libraries". Does that not mean dynamic linkage?

Comment: Yes, dynamic linkage

Comment: @user `what binary format(s) are these shared libraries in?` I really don't know how to find out? Is there any instructions? I'm running in linux.

Comment: Related: [Shared library name collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14820855/11107541), [How to deal with conflicting names of two shared libraries?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257335/550426)

Comment: okay so do you ever have to deal with DLLs?

Comment: @user it does indeed. Need to read closer.