# Rewriting symbols in static iOS libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, static-linking

I am working on an iOS app which links several static libraries. The challenge is, those linked libraries define same method names with different implementations. Oddly, I don't get any `duplicate symbol definition` errors; but, to no surprise, I end up with access to only one implementation of the method.

To be more clear, say I have libA and libB and they both define a global C method called func1()

When I link both libA and libB, and make a call to func1(), it resolves to either libA's or libB's implementation without any compilation warning. I, however, need to be able to access both libA's func1() and libB's func1() separately.

[There's a similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940384/how-to-deal-with-symbol-collisions-between-statically-linked-libraries/6940389#6940389) that explains how it can be done in C (via symbol renaming) but unfortunately, as I found out, `objcopy` tool doesn't work for ARM architecture (hence iPhone).

(I will submit it to the App Store, hence, dynamic linking is not an option)

Comment: If you have the source code for either of the libraries, then the solution is obvious. Alternatively, you could probably use `lipo` to package the two libraries into one, which *should* if my memory holds, keep only one of the symbols.

Comment: Thanks @RichardJ.RossIII but I don't have the source code and not sure your suggestion would help because I want to keep those symbols separately, I need them both, I don't want to reduce them to one symbol

Comment: I would say to use `dlopen` and `dlsym` to load the symbols in dynamically, and separately, but unfortunately that won't work now that apple bans those from use. I'm no expert at the structure of a `.a` file, but I have a feeling that it is possible to do this via a hex editor, manually. Let me try something, and I'll see if I can help you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you are in luck - you can still rename symbols with the ARM binary format, it's just a bit more hacky than the `objcopy` method...

NOTE: This has only been tested minimally, and I would strongly advise you to **make a backup** of all libraries in question before trying this!

Also note that this only works for files not compiled with the C++ compiler! This **will** fail if the C++ compiler was used on  these files.

1. First, you will need a decent hex editor, for this example, I will be using [Hex Fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/).
2. Next, you will open up a copy of your of of your libraries, let's call it `lib1-renamed.a`, and do the following with it:

   - Find the name of the symbol you wish to re-name. It can be found using the `nm` tool, or, if you know the header name, you should be set.
   - Next, you will use hex fiend, and to a textual replace of the old name (in this case `foo`), and give it a new name (in this case, `bar`). These names *must* have the same length, or it will corrupt the binary's offsets!

     <sup>*Note*: if there is more than one function that contain's `foo`'s name in it, you may have problems.</sup>
3. Now, you must edit the headers of the library you changed, to use the new function name (`bar`) instead of the old one.

If you have done the three simple<sup>†</sup> steps above properly, you should now be able to compile & link the two files successfully, and call both implementations.

If you are trying to do this with a universal binary (e.g. one the works on the simulator as well), you'd be best off using `lipo` to separate the two binaries, using `objcopy` on the i386/x64 binary, and then using my method on the ARM binary, and `lipo` it  back together.

<sup>†: Simplicity is not guaranteed, nor is it covered by the Richard J. Ross III super warranty. For more information about the super warranty, call 1-800-FREE-WARRANTY now. That's 1-800-FREE-WARRANTY now!</sup>

Comment: Testing this first thing tomorrow, greatly appreciate your effort (and your footnote even more!) :)

Comment: @EgeAkpinar Don't forget your free super warrantee!

Comment: Well turns out I don't need warranty, because it worked like a charm. I'd tried renaming before but missed that I should rename to same length. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AndiDog I appreciate your edit, but my humor is here to stay. Sometimes people take this site far too seriously, and a good laugh keeps you in a good mood.

Comment: This will be great if it works...  I will not be making a copy of the static library, however, as I am using source control.  Here goes nothing!  P.S. Is there no way to do this with `lipo` or some other command line tool?  I don't know enough about post-assembly development / penetration testing etc.