# duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMBase64

Tags: objective-c, duplicates, static-libraries

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMBase64 in:
>       ../../TCWeiboSDK/libTCWeiboSDK.a(GTMBase64.o)
>       ../../TBPlatform.framework/TBPlatform(GTMBase64.o)
>
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMBase64 in:
>       ../../TCWeiboSDK/libTCWeiboSDK.a(GTMBase64.o)
>       ../../TBPlatform.framework/TBPlatform(GTMBase64.o)
>
> ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This is my error. I already know the reason is both of two `lib` contain a class named `GTMBase64`, but these two lib are not open source. So I couldn't modify the source code easily.

I ever unpack both .a file using "otool" command and find that assembler code of `GTMBase64` in these two `lib` is different. At last, I have no idea how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few answers to this problem.

- You can wrap them each in their own wrapper (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6538625/1298400)
- You can rewrite them using `objcopy` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6940389/1298400)
- You can rewrite them with a Hex Editor (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15347275/1298400)

All of them are **heavy wizardry** and you will need to be careful to avoid very bad things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Both of them seems amazing. I think I should take my time to study.