# Prefix or remove classes from dynamic framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

Dealing with dynamic framework i am experiencing symbol conflicts errors which are best describe here: [Symbol collusions with third party framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781301/refer-classes-in-a-cocoa-touch-framework) 
The problem happens when third party framework is linked twice - in dynamic framework and in consumer project which use the framework and also import the third party framework as dependency

As i can see solutions for static frameworks which suggest removing classes from framework: [Removing classes from static library](http://atnan.com/blog/2012/01/12/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-errors-during-linking-by-removing-classes-from-static-libraries/) or prefixing classes [Prefix classes static framework](http://pdx.esri.com/blog/2013/12/13/namespacing-dependencies/) i am looking for solution for dynamic framework which have diffrent structure.

How is listing classed performed in dynamic framework? what are the actual files which contain the classes which will be compiled at runtime including third party embedded frameworks?

Comment: Michael, you should really post the issues here.  Your post is severely link(s) only.  I haven;t down voted it, but others will.

Comment: Also, Michael, I'll never understand why you guys who build frameworks just don't look at the source files for another framework like Parse.com who just went open source. Is it really the case that you can't glean some information on how to do this from them? There's a lot of frameworks out there and it seems like it should be a "look at what they did" type thing.