# Change Subroutine Names at Build Time to Avoid Collisions in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, collision

**BACKGROUND**

I'm building an iOS app (which I'll just call `MyApp` from here) that will rely on calculations done by several separate static libraries (which I'll call `Lib1`, `Lib2`, `Lib3`,...).  Each library is built in it's own project, then imported into a single workspace (so the workspace will contain `MyApp`, `Lib1`, `Lib2`, ...).  More details on how this is set up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655931/xcode-4-3-static-library-generation?rq=1).  The libraries are used by other products that are independent from `MyApp`, so I want to minimize any changes in the libraries.  The libraries are also written in (plain) `C`, so there are no header files.

Certain function names are used by multiple libraries (so both `Lib1` and `Lib2` might each have a `DoStuff` method).  Functions with the same name generally do the same thing, but there are some specifics about how that do it that can be different between libraries, so the actual code in `DoStuff` on `Lib1` might be quite different than the code in `DoStuff` on `Lib2`.  It would be very difficult to write one universal `DoStuff` that would be exactly the same in each library.

**THE ISSUE**

While the app is running, it isn't calling the correct `DoStuff` from the correct library.  I found out about this because the wrong function was called during a debug session (which eventually caused the app to crash, due to the subtle differences in the `DoStuff` functions).

**WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR**

Each library has only one entry point from `MyApp`, and each entry point is uniquely named.  If `DoStuff` is called from the entry point method of `Lib1` (or any other method on `Lib1`, for that matter), then I want it to call the `DoStuff` method on `Lib1`.  What's the best way to make that happen?

Is there any way (maybe through a setting somewhere in XCode) I can make it so that each library is it's own namespace?  That would be my preferred way to fix the issue.  I guess I could go through and rename the duplicate functions so that they are all unique (so the `DoStuff` method on `Lib1` could be renamed to `Lib1DoStuff`, or something similar), but there are hundreds of functions that could have duplicate names, and we are going to be adding hundreds of libraries to the project, so having to go in and rename all the functions by hand and fix all the calls to them would take a significant amount of time, and my boss doesn't see that as a viable option.

---

**UPDATE**

After looking at the comments from Josh Caswell and some of the links he provided, it looks like it might be possible to automatically rename all the functions when the libraries are compiled, and that would be the best way to try to fix **`THE ISSUE`** above.  From what I've seen, the `objcopy` that gets mentioned in a couple of the links in the comments isn't support on iOS.  I eventually came across [this](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/02/xcode-build-rules/) blog entry, which talks about creating custom build rules for Xcode targets, and [this](https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/build-process/) blog that talks about custom build settings and build phases.

**Am I right to assume that I can use scripts at some point in the build process to automatically append to the name of all the functions in each of my libraries, instead of doing it manually as I described in the last paragraph of the `WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR` section above?**  **If so, which is the correct part of the build process to make those changes?  Lastly, what would the syntax look like for doing something like that?**  The 'scripts' used in the different parts of the build processes certainly doesn't look like Obj-C.  I've never used these 'scripts' before, so I'm completely in the dark on how I'd use them, and that's what I'm looking for help with.

I tried to be as clear as I could, but if there are any questions on what I'm asking please let me know.

Comment: Are these `DoStuff` methods actually _methods_, or are they _functions_? If they're methods, is there some kind of inheritance relationship between their classes? Or are they methods on the _same_ class, maybe (in which case you're talking about Undefined Behavior)? How are you determining that the wrong code is being run in response to an invocation of this single name?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, they are functions written in C.  I've edited my question.  There isn't really any kind of class or inheritance relationship between the separate libraries.  I know the wrong code is being called from stepping through the code in a debug session.

Comment: Okay, cool. There's no namespacing in C, and ObjC does not add any outside of the implicit namespacing of methods on classes. It now sounds like you're looking at this situation: [How to deal with symbol collisions between statically linked libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6940384)

Comment: Also see: [What should I do if two libraries provide a function with the same name?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/678254)

Comment: @JoshCaswell: hm, those look promising - thanks for the links.  I'll take a closer look and give it a try.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I took a closer look at those links, and it says in the comments that `objcopy` isn't supported on iOS.  Those comments are a bit old, do they still apply?  I've seen the `#define` stuff before, but I'm not really familiar with the compiler commands - is that something that can be done in XCode?

Comment: I've never used objcopy myself. If the library is pure C there shouldn't be any problem regardless of platform, though. It's just changing symbols, not any of the parts that move bytes around.

Comment: `DoStuff` is static method ?

Comment: @NhatDinh: Yes, it is a static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Why isn't xcode calling the correct library function?**

Let's say I have 3 C libraries as mentioned by you. Let's say it has the following code.

**Library 1 - test1lib.a with code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void doStuff()
{
  printf("\nDoing stuff for lib1\n");
}

void uniqueEntryPoint1()
{
  printf("\nUnique entry point for lib1\n");
  doStuff();
}
```

**Library 2 - test2lib.a with code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void doStuff()
{
  printf("\nDoing stuff for lib2\n");
}

void uniqueEntryPoint2()
{
  printf("\nUnique entry point for lib2\n");
  doStuff();
}
```

**Library 3 - test3lib.a with code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void doStuff()
{
  printf("\nDoing stuff for lib3\n");
}

void uniqueEntryPoint3()
{
  printf("\nUnique entry point for lib3\n");
  doStuff();
}
```

Here each library has a unique function and one common function `doStuff()`

When we add these 3 libraries to xcode and link them. xcode links but does not load all the objects files. Let's say the objective C code is like this:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    uniqueEntryPoint1();

}
```

The output is

```
Unique entry point for lib1

Doing stuff for lib1
```

In this case xcode will only load symbols which are referred (library 1 objects) in this case.

If you are read about linker flags/options such as `-all_load`, `-force_load`  and `-objC`, you will have better understanding.

If we add `-all_load` linker option, it will force linker to load all the objects of libraries so we will get the following error in xcode

```
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The reason this fails as the linker detects that `doStuff()` is redefined multiple times.

The only way around this problem is change the linker input i.e. symbols present in these 3 libraries. This is already mentioned by Josh in the comments. I will add my $0.02 to it.

### Possible Solutions

**Solution 1:**

The best solution (self explanatory) is to change the source code if you have access to the same.

**Solution 2:**

Use objcopy to rename or prefix the function as provided in the answer of this [How to deal with symbol collisions between statically linked libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940384/how-to-deal-with-symbol-collisions-between-statically-linked-libraries)

Now your doubt on how to find the objcopy.

*Option 1:*
You can use this project https://github.com/RodAtDISA/llvm-objcopy. This will be tricky to compile as it builds along with llvm. You will have to follow instructions at http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html and http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html.

If you rewrite the https://github.com/RodAtDISA/llvm-objcopy/blob/master/llvm-objcopy.cpp, you can probably reuse the parsing and object rewriting logic without depending upon llvm.

*Option 2:*

Compile and reuse binutils objcopy from https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=binutils/objcopy.c;h=2636ab4bcb34cf1e1e54db9933018a805b366727;hb=HEAD

**Solution 3:**

You can follow the answer provided by Richard in this link [Rewriting symbols in static iOS libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345491/rewriting-symbols-in-static-ios-libraries). This is more of a hack but using a hex editor you can rewrite the symbols if their length is kept the same. If you have more symbols and its a big library, you can consider using https://sourceforge.net/projects/bbe-/ and nm to write a script.

All of this is a considerable effort but apparently there is no shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for spelling everything out in so much detail.  I was hoping there would be an easier way, but it looks like this is all there is.