# An objcopy equivalent for Windows? (Hack for clashing lib symbols)

Tags: c++, collision, symbols, libs

I'm looking for a Windows equivalent of the GNU tool **objcopy**. I'm looking to implement the [suggestion posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6940389/2065863) to my problem, however I need to do it cross-platform (Windows, Linux and Mac). I couldn't find the answer on my google friend, so perhaps the solution needs to be implemented differently. Thank you!

Comment: For use on Visual C++ built files, or on e.g. MinGW/Cygwin built files? In the latte case there should be an `objcopy` that you can use straight off.

Comment: Its Visual C++ built files.

Comment: I don't know if this is an option for you, but you could just start from ELF linux version, use objcopy and then try the conversion to COFF/PE with the tool released here: agner.org/optimize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of the default MSVC tooling: `LIB /EXTRACT` extracts a copy of an object; `LIB /REMOVE` then removes it from the library.

I think `LIB /DEF /EXPORT:externalName=internalName` also would be beneficial to you, when you put the object file back in.

Comment: Will that allow me to put a prefix on the symbols?

Comment: @Deathicon: Haven't tried it, but I believe that's what `EXPORT:prefix_Symbol=Symbol` does.

Comment: I came across this issue and couldn't get your solution to work with static libraries. Do you have some link that demonstrate this solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a hack, replacing all the instances of the conflicting name by a different name of the same length in one of the library bin file can work. Do this at your own risks.

Example

```
// a.h
void doSomething();

// b.h
void doSomething();
```

We can replace `doSomething` by `doSomethink`

In python it would be something like:

```
f = open('b.lib',"rb")
s = f.read()
f.close()
s = s.replace(b'doSomething',b'doSomethink')
f = open('b.lib',"wb")
f.write(s)
f.close()
```

And modify b header accordingly

```
// b.h
void doSomethink();
```

Note that here I used the plain function name as defined in the header to match the symbol in the binary but you might want to use the full mangled name instead to prevent unwanted replacements.