# The common ways of resolving C naming collision

Tags: c++, c, linker

I have two static libraries (say A and B) and both of them reference an identical third party library (say C) by including the source files directly and independently. C is pretty simple and only have one .h and .c files. Executable D links with A and B.

Let's assume there is a function `fn` in C. When executable D resolves the function name: `fn`, it picks arbitrary `fn` implementation within either A or B.

My question is how to make sure the codes within A references the A's C implementation and B references B's C implementation?

As C is a third party library, so I'd not modify C's codes. So renaming either one of functions doesn't work. I ever consider uses namespace of C++ that wrap C's code like following

```
namespace WRAP
{
#include "moudule_c_source_file.c"
}
```

However, as module_c_souce_file.c includes module_c_source_file.h which contains `extern "C"` declare. This causes the generated symbol object file doesn't contains namespace information. So that executable D still links arbitrary function implementation.

Any idea of resolving my question mentioned above without touching the third party library codes?

Comment: You can use a bunch of `#define`s to effectively rename external names in your C library.

Comment: It should not matter which lib is used due to "one definition rule". Otherwise your program invokes undefined behavior

Comment: Are these static or dynamic libraries? On which os?

Comment: @AlanBirtles A and B are static library, C actually is one .h and one .c files and added into A and B directly. Operating System: Windows

Comment: If they're static libraries there isn't much you can do without modifying C

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940384/how-to-deal-with-symbol-collisions-between-statically-linked-libraries/6940389#6940389 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052228/an-objcopy-equivalent-for-windows-hack-for-clashing-lib-symbols

Answer (score 0):

Possibility of the following idea depends on how big third-party libs are. The only idea I have is to create your own mid-layer-libraries. For example, mid-layer-library-A.dll uses  A, and mid-layer-library-B.dll uses B. So, mid-layer-library-A.dll imports fn from A and exports mid_A_fn, mid-layer-library-B.dll imports fn from B and exports mid_B_fn. And executable D links to mid-layer-libraries and C. So, D has three defferent methods: mid_A_fn, mid_B_fn and fn from C.
Something like design pattern 'adapter'.

Answer (score 0):

> When executable D resolves the function name: fn, it picks arbitrary fn implementation within either A or B.

No, it does not. It picks the *first* definition available, and which one that is depends on the order of `A` and `B` on `D`s link line.

> how to make sure the codes within A references the A's C implementation and B references B's C implementation?

In the scenario you described, `D` will contain a *single* definition (from either `A` or `B`), so your question makes no sense.

In addition, since `fn` is *identical*, it *can't matter* which definition is used.

If `fn`s are not in fact identical, you have an ODR violation and your binary has undefined behavior.