# Can code for a library function be contained several times in an executable?

Tags: c, linker, executable

I am wondering if it could happen that, in a programm written in C, the code for a function from a static library is contained twice in an executable.

For example, assume that you create a static library lib_a which uses functions from another static library lib_b. Then you create a programm that uses both lib_a and lib_b. Would the executable for this programm contain the code for the functions from lib_b twice? If not, how is this avoided?

My understanding of the linker and of the format of an executable is very rough; sorry if this question is quite basic. Maybe somebody knows a good reference for this topic? I have searched several books on C, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: It will be contained twice, if you don't want it you should create a lib_c with the merge of lib_b and lib_a and replace in the source file lib_b and lib_a by lib_c. some more explanations [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library) and [here](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_C_libraries.html)

Comment: @Yann Are you sure? With global variables one could not have multiple definitions linked together. With global functions one can?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940384/how-to-deal-with-symbol-collisions-between-statically-linked-libraries

Comment: I'm still waiting for the expert programmer but meanwhile let me check my understanding. Creating a static library lib_b which uses functions from lib_a doesn't mean to include code from lib_a in lib_b. lib_b will have "unresolved references" to functions in lib_a (lib_a doesn't even have to be present when lib_b is created). In fact, in the typical unix environment it's at least unusual and difficult to produce a library which has all its dependencies resolved, because that step is usually done when linking the executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert `lib_b` to a shared library on top of what @Yann suggests

Answer (score 0):

Suppose library `lib_a.a` (a Unix-style static library) contains a function `a1_function()`, and `a1_function()` calls another function `b1_function()` that is found in `lib_b.a`.

Suppose your program calls `a1_function()` directly, and also calls another function, `b2_function()`, from `lib_b.a` directly.

Your linker command might look like:

```
c99 -o program program.c -l_a -l_b
```

You cannot link your program without mentioning both `lib_a.a` (as `-l_a` or by pathname) and `lib_b.a`.  Even if you later revise your program so it no longer calls `b2_function()`, you will still need both libraries, because `lib_a.a` only contains its own code, not the code that is in `lib_b.a`.

With shared libraries, it might be possible for to link the revised program (with no direct call to `b2_function()`) with just `-l_a` and rely on the metadata in `lib_a.so` to tell the linker to link with `lib_b.so` too.

If you revise `lib_a.a` so it contains not only `a1_function()` but also the code for `b1_function()` and any supporting code necessary to support it (which will exclude `b2_function()` for the purposes of this discussion).  Then the program that calls just `a1_function()` would not need `lib_b.a` at all.  However, if the program calls `b2_function()`, then you will need to link with both libraries.  The material from `lib_a.a` that satisfied `b1_function()` and its dependencies will come from `lib_a.a`; the function `b2_function()` and any supporting material it needs that was not provided by `lib_a.a` will also be linked in.

If the code from `lib_b` included in `lib_a.a` is different from the 'same' code in `lib_b.a`, then you have potential for aberrant behaviour.  An extreme case of this might be an object file, `b_file1.c`, which contains a number of functions including `b1_function()` and `b2_function()`.  When compiled for inclusion in `lib_a.a`, the `b2_function()` is not included; when compiled for inclusion in `lib_b.a`, the `b2_function()` *is* included (and `b1_function()` is always included).  Then you will fail to link the program when it calls `b2_function()` because the program will link `b_file1.o` from `lib_a.a` to satisfy the `b1_function()` reference, but the linker will also try to link `b_file1.o` from `lib_b.a` to satisfy the `b2_function()` reference.  This leads to two definitions of function `b1_function()`, and that isn't allowed (under static library linking rules).  With shared libraries, it isn't entirely clear what would happen, but there are a number of ways that things could go wrong (but errors for doubly-defined symbols wouldn't be one of those ways).

Note that you should studiously avoid circumstances where a function in `lib_a.a` calls a function in `lib_b.a` and a function in `lib_b.a` calls a function in `lib_a.a`.  This leads to circular dependency problems, and can mean you need to list libraries multiple times on a command line.  It would be far better to create a single library, `lib_c.a` containing the material from both `lib_a.a` and `lib_b.a` and link with that, once.