# Copy SRC directory with adding a prefix to all c-library functions

Tags: c, preprocessor, static-libraries, prefix

I have a embedded C static library that communicates with a hardware peripheral. It currently does not support multiple hardware peripherals, but I need to interface to a second one. I do not care about code footprint rightnow. So I want to duplicate that library; one for each hardware.

This of course, will result in symbol collision. A good method is to use objcopy to add a prefix to object files. So I can get hw1_fun1.o and hw2_fun1.o. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940384/how-to-deal-with-symbol-collisions-between-statically-linked-libraries) illustrates it.

I want to add a prefix to all c functions on the source level, not the object. Because I will need to modify a little bit for hw2.

Is there any script, c-preprocessor, tool that can make something like:

```
./scriptme --prefix=hw2 ~/src/ ~/dest/
```

I'll be grateful :)

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of the library?

Comment: If you can edit the source code, you may be better off using macros to help generate unique names.

Comment: @GáborImre: Yes, I have the source code

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: Can you give an example please? The library is very large, so edits are limited to sed replaces, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a simple bash script that does the required function, or sort of. I hope it help someone one day.

```
#!/bin/sh

DIR_BIN=bin/ext/lwIP/
DIR_SRC=src/ext/lwIP/
DIR_DST=src/hw2_lwIP/
CMD_NM=mb-nm

[ -d $DIR_DST ] || ( echo "Destination directory does not exist!" && exit 1 );
cp -r $DIR_SRC/* $DIR_DST/
chmod -R 755 $DIR_DST # cygwin issue with Windows7
sync                  # file permissions. (Pure MS shit!)

funs=`find $DIR_BIN -name *.o | xargs $CMD_NM | grep " R \| T " | awk '{print $3}'`
echo "Found $(echo $funs | wc -w) functions, processing:"
for fun in $funs; 
do
    echo "  $fun";
    find $DIR_DST -type f -exec sed -i "s/$fun/hw2_$fun/g" {} \;
done;

echo "Done! Now change includes and compile your project ;-)"
```