# How to add prefix to symbols of a static library (Windows)

Tags: c++, static-libraries, collision, symbols

I'm facing a LNK2005 error as I'm trying to link to 2 third party libraries with colliding symbols. The closest thing I could find was [How to deal with symbol collisions between statically linked libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940384/how-to-deal-with-symbol-collisions-between-statically-linked-libraries)

However I'm still struggling to find a tool that would allow me to add a prefix to symbols of one of the libraries (something similar to `objcopy --prefix-symbols=foo_ foo.o` , but for Windows).

Comment: Have you tried FORCE:MULTIPLE as an alternative yet? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70abkas3.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The FORCE:Multiple command allows it to build, but then crashes on launch.

Comment: Resolved by namespacing and recompiling one of the libraries