# Namespacing plain C headers

Tags: c++, c, namespaces

Namespacing headers in C++ is as easy as wrapping the header in

```
namespace SomeNs { ... }
```

Namespacing the corresponding the object file or static library wasn't straightforward because of name mangling, [but I seem to have found a way regardless](https://github.com/pjump/c-ns/blob/master/bin/c%2B%2Bns)

On the other hand, plain C object files / static libraries should be even easier to namespace because there's already 
`objcopy --prefix-symbols` and `C` doesn't mangle symbols, but What is the `objcopy --prefix-symbols` counterpart for header files?

Comment: I don't think there is one.

Comment: It is exactly what you already suggested.  Put the namespace declaration around every `#include` naming the header in question, or put it directly in the file.  If the latter, you can protect it with conditional compilation directives so that the namespace declaration is seen only when you compile in C++ mode.  The latter is probably more reliable, and it is the same treatment often given to `extern "c"` declarations (which you must *avoid*, as it normally suppresses name mangling).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940384/how-to-deal-with-symbol-collisions-between-statically-linked-libraries

Comment: @Toby Thanks but I would really like an automated/automatable solution.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Of course that method is automatable, ;D I just got to get the symbols for the redefines  from the corresponding object file (with `nm`) rather than from the header file  (don't know how to do that).