# Symbol redefinition error between libxml2 and theos

Tags: c, theos, cydia, redefinition, cydia-substrate

I am using libxml2 in a tweak, but I get a symbol redefinition error. Looks like some DataAccess-structs.h from theos uses the same xmlNode struct similar to libxml. Since, both of these are shared libraries that maybe used by other applications, I am not sure how to solve it without breaking everything.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h:488:8: error: 
      redefinition of '_xmlNode'
struct _xmlNode {
       ^
<User_home>/Documents/substrate/theos/include/DataAccess/DataAccess-Structs.h:16:16: note: 
      previous definition is here
typedef struct _xmlNode {
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/678254/694576

Answer (score 0):

So I went through some options [posted in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/678254/694576) and figured that dynamically loading the library at runtime is the better of the evils. using `objcopy` or trying to relink as static library is not good given that these are shared libraries across many applications.

The fundamental idea is to use `dlopen`, `dlsym` and `dlclose` to accomplish the task. However, the problem is not just in linking but also in compilation. To solve the compilation problem you have two options
a) Use `#define` to redefine the symbol name as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940384/how-to-deal-with-symbol-collisions-between-statically-linked-libraries).
b) Use abstract pointers (`void*`) and totally avoid all the xml structures.

Option (a) has a drawback in that you have to redefine every colliding symbol of libxml2 and theos whereas Option (b) may lead to incorrect cast by using void* or xml structs.

I chose option (b) and is how you do it if you did the same

Create a list of typedef for the xmlElements that you want to use. I was using libxml as a writer and hence I typdef all the writer structures.

```
typedef void* (*xmlNewTextWriterFilenameFPtr)(const char *uri, int compression);
typedef int (*xmlTextWriterStartDocumentFPtr)(void *writer,const char *version,const char *encoding,const char *standalone);
typedef int (*xmlTextWriterEndDocumentFPtr)(void *writer);
```

Then for every method that you have to call use `dlopen` and `dlsym`.

```
void *lib=dlopen(path_to_libxml,RTLD_LOCAL);
const char *func_xmlNewTextWriterFilename = "xmlNewTextWriterFilename";
if(lib == NULL){printf("%s","Problem loading library");} 
xmlNewTextWriterFilenamePtr fptrWriter=(xmlNewTextWriterFilenamePtr)dlsym(lib, func_xmlNewTextWriterFilename);
void *writer=fptrWriter(OUT_FILE_PATH,0);
```