# How to build RestKit and facebook-ios-sdk together?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2, restkit, facebook-ios-sdk

My project links with [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) and facebook-ios-sdk, Xcode gives an error:

```
Duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJSON in .../facebook-ios-sdk/libfacebook_ios_sdk.a(SBJSON.o) and  .../Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJSON.o for architecture i386
```

How can I fixed it?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300867/how-can-i-avoid-duplicate-symbol-errors-in-xcode-with-shared-static-libraries